# level set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the following statement:

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function with $f(0)=0$, consider $\{x\in \mathbb{R^n}: f(x)=s\}=c(s)$ (note that $c(s)$ is level set) then $c(s)$ is compact.

Well, I honestly don't know if this is true or not, because it's something I need for another Theorem; but this is my attempt:

i) $c(s)$ is closed set:

Given $c\in \mathbb{R}$, Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in c(s)$ (well here I assume that c(s) has infinite points) such that $x_n \to x$ when $n \to \infty$ since $f$ is continuos function then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ and sinces $f(x_n)=s$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $f(x)=s$ This proof that $c(s)$ is closed set.

ii) $c(s)$ is bounded

I'm stuck here.

If statement is false, what hypotesis do I need?

What happened if I assume that

$f$ is a function with a local minima at $0$ and no has other critical points?

Comment: Well you need the hypothesis that the level set is bounded.

Comment: I think that requiring the function to be convex is enough to ensure this.

Answer (score 2):

Without the level set being bounded,  you are toast.  Simple counterexample, any periodic function
$$f(x)=\sin x$$

The level sets are either empty or unbounded

Comment: Simpler example:  $f(x) \equiv 0$.  What you know is that $c(s)$ is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function, so that it is necessarily closed.  If it's also bounded, then it's compact.  And in $\Bbb R^n$, no unbounded set can be compact (cover it by concentric balls of radius increasing to $\infty$), so this condition is sufficient as well as being necessary.

Comment: @RobertShore What happened if I assume that $f$ is a function with a local minima at 0 and no has other critical points?

Comment: @MathisAwesome Wouldn't that force $0$ to be the only zero of $f$?

Comment: If it's $C^1$, then if $0$ is the only critical point, the function is monotonic on each side of $0$ so your level sets will be at most 2 points each, and thus trivially compact

Comment: @Alan Well I believe you are involucring a partial orden.